# WebSocket service in Angular2, accessing the parent component

Tags: angular, websocket, angular2-services, angular2-components

I am trying to implement my own way of using WebSockets in angular2, and I am facing a really silly problem.

I have a service defined, that had a method which would give you back a WebSocket object, by getting a url and two functions, one to serve as the "onmessage" and one for "onerror" (I have hard coded the "onopen" and "onclose" as they are not varying from component to component):

```
    @Injectable()
export class WsService {

    createWebSocket(url: string, onMessage: (e: Event) => any, onError: (e: Event) => any ): WebSocket {
        let ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.onopen = function(evt: Event) {
            console.log("Connected!");
        }
        ws.onclose = function(evt: Event) {
            console.log("Disconnected!");
        }
        ws.onmessage = onMessage;
        ws.onerror = onError;
        return ws;
    }
}
```

Then in my appComponent I instantiate a WebSocket object, like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.ws = this._ws.createWebSocket("ws://localhost:63562", this.on_msg, this.on_err);
}

on_msg(e: Event) {
      this.blah = e["data"];
  }

  on_err(e: Event) {
      console.log(e);
  }
```

Now the problem is, even though the "on_msg" function is defined in the AppComponent, it sees itself as part of the WebSocket Object so it cannot access and manipulate variables defined in the AppComponent.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use an already made library such as this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-websocket-service

It would leverage the errors you can find and are usually based on best practises...

[edit]
RxJS has something equivalent as well:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts